# Is it possible to publish maven artifact without pom.xml?

Tags: gradle

we have quite unique situation. We are packaging native binaries from both linux and Windows platforms from different machines (Ubuntu & Windows 7). We are using standard `maven-publish` plugin.

We are publishing artifacts with the same Maven GAV and they only differ in `classifier`. This is causing problems during publishing as the 2nd platform will try to publish the `pom.xml`, which is already published. The deployment user has no overwrite access by purpose.

Is there any way to publish maven artifacts without publishing the `pom.xml` ?

Comment: I am in the same situation -- what did your team end up doing?

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this issue too and I could not for the life of me figure out how to make a new publication with just the jar. I would put the artifactJar and it would error and I ran out of time.

So I just went ahead and created a script that calls several of these:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=<group-id> \
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
  -Dversion=<version> \
  -Dpackaging=<type-of-packaging> \
  -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
  -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

These just deploy straight to the maven repo without the pom.xml. So no deps will come with your jar, you just get the jar itself.

So I just put this as a `publishStandaloneJar` Exec task that dependsOn=jar. Works for now. I'll go back and take another shot at this some other time to do it right.

Comment: Using this answer to specifically address the OP, you can add "-DgeneratePom=false" to avoid publishing a POM.  See: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#generatePom

Answer (score 1):

I use IvyPublication to achieve this.  I found this thread as I was trying to clean up the script to only use one plugin and was attempting to replace the Ivy Publication with Maven, only to find it kindly was generating a pom.

If you happen to be using artifactory plugin, there is a global config option publishPom = true by default, it can be switched off.

In my case I do want pom's published for jar files, but I'm also publishing rpms which have no need of a pom.

```
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'
publishing {
    publications {
        rpm(IvyPublication) {
            organisation publishGroup
            //We'll set the version and module when we build the rpm
        }
    }
}
buildRpm{
...
    publishing.publications.rpm.setModule(rpmName)
    publishing.publications.rpm.setRevision(rpmVersion) 

    //add rpm to publications
    publishing.publications.rpm.artifact(destFile) {
        type "rpm"
        extension "rpm"
        builtBy buildRpm
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Publishing to maven without a pom.xml does not make sense. Try this:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

task ubuntuZip(type: Zip) {
    classifier 'ubuntu'
    // TODO configure
}
task windows7Zip(type: Zip) {
    classifier 'windows7'
    // TODO configure
}
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact ubuntuZip
            artifact windows7Zip
            artifact [source: 'path/to/random/file.txt', classifier: 'foo']
        }
    }
}
```

See [MavenPublication.artifact(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/MavenPublication.html#artifact%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: This will not work as the artifacts are built on different operating systems - Linux and Windows. One OS does not have access to the other's artifacts and vice versa.

Answer (score -2):

You need the `pom.xml` file which includes more information about your artifact, as a dependence.

Comment: pom.xml is not needed. It depends on the artifact.  In my case I am publishing installers that have no traditional dependencies, the pom.xml is useless.